# Where to install SSL Certificate in MMC console for mutual (peer-peer) authentication

Tags: c#, sockets, authentication, ssl-certificate, mmc

I had to do a mutual SSL authentication for peer-peer communication not localhost(from one machine to another). This is done asynchronously using Microsoft.Net **Socket** Communication Class along with **SslStream** class **BeginAuthenticateAsServer** and **BeginAuthenticateAsClient** having **ValidateServerCertificate** and **ValidateClientCertificate** callbacks.
For this i have created self-signed certificates comprising of

•   Root Certificate

•   Server Certificate

•   Client Certificate

To generate the aforementioned certificates I placed the makecert.exe and pvk2pfx.exe in a folder and then ran the below commands.

**Root Certificate Creation command**

-To create .cer and generate private key

*makecert.exe -n "CN=abc.com" -r -pe -a sha512 -len 4096 -sky signature -cy authority -sv RootCert.pvk RootCert.cer*

-To create .pfx using the .cer and private key

*pvk2pfx -pvk RootCert.pvk -spc RootCert.cer -pfx RootCert.pfx -po test123*

**Server Certificate creation command**

-To create .cer and generate private key

*makecert.exe -pe -n "CN=abc.com" -a sha512 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic RootCert.cer -iv RootCert.pvk -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv ServerCert.pvk ServerCert.cer*

-To create .pfx using the .cer and private key

*pvk2pfx -pvk ServerCert.pvk -spc ServerCert.cer -pfx ServerCert.pfx -po test123*

**Client Certificate creation command**

-To create .cer and generate private key

*makecert.exe -pe -n "CN=abc.com" -a sha512 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -ic RootCert.cer -iv RootCert.pvk -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv ClientCert.pvk ClientCert.cer*

-To create .pfx using the .cer and private key

*pvk2pfx -pvk ClientCert.pvk -spc ClientCert.cer -pfx ClientCert.pfx -po test123*

For mutual peer-peer authentication, where do I need to put these certificates in MMC console? Do I need to install these in The local machine store or The current user store?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Root certificate must be installed in the Trusted Root CAs container of computer store (LocalMachine\Root) and authentication certificates must be installed in the personal container of computer store (LocalMachine\My).

BTW, makecert.exe is deprecated tool and is not recommended for use even for testing. Instead, you should consider to use CertEnroll COM interfaces, certreq.exe tool (with templated INF file) or use [New-SelfSignedCertificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet. Be aware that this cmdlet uses CNG key storage provider, so it may not be usable in .NET natively.

An example of CertEnroll COM interface usage in PowerShell is in my blog post: [Self-signed certificate creation with PowerShell](http://en-us.sysadmins.lv/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=99) and updated version on [TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6).